# Powershell comparing CSVs

Tags: csv, powershell

I have two csv files as such:

1) Records.csv

```
Account,TransactionDate,Description,Amount
Acct1,1/1/2015,Shopping at Kohls,($35.00)
Acct1,1/1/2016,Shopping at Target,($25.22)
Acct1,1/1/2016,Shopping at Target,($60.00)
Acct2,4/5/2015,Subway,($9.12)
Acct2,1/1/2016,Jimmy Johns,($11.00)
Acct3,1/1/2016,Shopping at Kohls,($35.00)
Acct1,1/1/2016,Shopping at Kohls,$35.00 
Acct1,1/1/2016,Shopping at Target,($60.00)
Acct2,4/5/2015,Subway,($9.12)
Acct2,1/1/2016,Jimmy Johns,($11.00)
Acct2,1/1/2016,Jimmy Johns,($11.00)
Acct3,1/1/2016,Shopping at Kohls,($35.00)
Acct3,1/1/2016,Kroger,($27.00)
```

and 2) rules.csv:

```
Description,Category,Topic
Shopping at Kohls,Misc,Clothing
Subway,Food,Restaurants
Jimmy Johns,Food,Restaurants
Shopping at Target,Misc,Home
Kroger,Food,Groceries
```

I need to append the category and topic from rules.csv into the records.csv file, based on matching description.

When I run the following code, it works but appends the entire line in rules.csv into one field. I need to append it into separate columns.

```
$rules = import-csv "rules.CSV"
import-csv "Records.csv" | % {
   $desc=$_.Description
   $_ | Add-Member NoteProperty "Category" ($rules | select-string -SimpleMatch $desc ) -PassThru
} | export-csv "output.csv" -notype
```

The output looks like this but I need to split the last column.

```
"Account","TransactionDate","Description","Amount","Category"
"Acct1","1/1/2015","Shopping at Kohls","($35.00)","@{Description=Shopping at Kohls; Category=Misc; Topic=Clothing}"
"Acct1","1/1/2016","Shopping at Target","($25.22)","@{Description=Shopping at Target; Category=Misc; Topic=Home}"
"Acct1","1/1/2016","Shopping at Target","($60.00)","@{Description=Shopping at Target; Category=Misc; Topic=Home}"
"Acct2","4/5/2015","Subway","($9.12)","@{Description=Subway; Category=Food; Topic=Restaurants}"
"Acct2","1/1/2016","Jimmy Johns","($11.00)","@{Description=Jimmy Johns; Category=Food; Topic=Restaurants}"
"Acct3","1/1/2016","Shopping at Kohls","($35.00)","@{Description=Shopping at Kohls; Category=Misc; Topic=Clothing}"
"Acct1","1/1/2016","Shopping at Kohls","$35.00 ","@{Description=Shopping at Kohls; Category=Misc; Topic=Clothing}"
"Acct1","1/1/2016","Shopping at Target","($60.00)","@{Description=Shopping at Target; Category=Misc; Topic=Home}"
"Acct2","4/5/2015","Subway","($9.12)","@{Description=Subway; Category=Food; Topic=Restaurants}"
"Acct2","1/1/2016","Jimmy Johns","($11.00)","@{Description=Jimmy Johns; Category=Food; Topic=Restaurants}"
"Acct2","1/1/2016","Jimmy Johns","($11.00)","@{Description=Jimmy Johns; Category=Food; Topic=Restaurants}"
"Acct3","1/1/2016","Shopping at Kohls","($35.00)","@{Description=Shopping at Kohls; Category=Misc; Topic=Clothing}"
"Acct3","1/1/2016","Kroger","($27.00)","@{Description=Kroger; Category=Food; Topic=Groceries}"
```

Any way to do that?

Comment: You need to _"split the last column,"_ how?  You want `Category` and `Topic` pulled out as well?  `Description` looks to already be intact and present, so can you also provide a few lines of what you *expect* the output to look like, just to save everyone time and any confusion?  :)

Comment: @gravity thank you. Yes I would need the Category and Topic matching the description pulled out. Column Headers can be Category and Topic. I did not want it in this array notation that I show above. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

used this

https://github.com/RamblingCookieMonster/PowerShell/blob/master/Join-Object.ps1

```
$a = @'
Account,TransactionDate,Description,Amount
Acct1,1/1/2015,Shopping at Kohls,($35.00)
Acct1,1/1/2016,Shopping at Target,($25.22)
Acct1,1/1/2016,Shopping at Target,($60.00)
Acct2,4/5/2015,Subway,($9.12)
Acct2,1/1/2016,Jimmy Johns,($11.00)
Acct3,1/1/2016,Shopping at Kohls,($35.00)
Acct1,1/1/2016,Shopping at Kohls,$35.00 
Acct1,1/1/2016,Shopping at Target,($60.00)
Acct2,4/5/2015,Subway,($9.12)
Acct2,1/1/2016,Jimmy Johns,($11.00)
Acct2,1/1/2016,Jimmy Johns,($11.00)
Acct3,1/1/2016,Shopping at Kohls,($35.00)
Acct3,1/1/2016,Kroger,($27.00)
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

$b = @'
Description,Category,Topic
Shopping at Kohls,Misc,Clothing
Subway,Food,Restaurants
Jimmy Johns,Food,Restaurants
Shopping at Target,Misc,Home
Kroger,Food,Groceries
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

Join-Object $a $b -LeftJoinProperty description -RightJoinProperty description

# output:
# Account TransactionDate Description        Amount   Category Topic      
# ------- --------------- -----------        ------   -------- -----      
# Acct3   1/1/2016        Kroger             ($27.00) Food     Groceries  
# Acct2   4/5/2015        Subway             ($9.12)  Food     Restaurants
# Acct2   4/5/2015        Subway             ($9.12)  Food     Restaurants
# Acct1   1/1/2016        Shopping at Target ($25.22) Misc     Home       
# Acct1   1/1/2016        Shopping at Target ($60.00) Misc     Home       
# Acct1   1/1/2016        Shopping at Target ($60.00) Misc     Home       
# Acct2   1/1/2016        Jimmy Johns        ($11.00) Food     Restaurants
# Acct2   1/1/2016        Jimmy Johns        ($11.00) Food     Restaurants
# Acct2   1/1/2016        Jimmy Johns        ($11.00) Food     Restaurants
# Acct1   1/1/2015        Shopping at Kohls  ($35.00) Misc     Clothing   
# Acct3   1/1/2016        Shopping at Kohls  ($35.00) Misc     Clothing   
# Acct1   1/1/2016        Shopping at Kohls  $35.00   Misc     Clothing   
# Acct3   1/1/2016        Shopping at Kohls  ($35.00) Misc     Clothing
```

*edit: if you dont want to use the other script, this should also work

```
foreach ($record in $a) {
    foreach ($obj in $b) {
        if ($obj.description -eq $record.description) {
            $record | select *, @{n='Category';e={$obj.Category}}, @{n='Topic';e={$obj.Topic}}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you - this seems to do exactly what I need. However, I am such a newbie, I don't even know how to import a PS file to make these functions available. Googling that and trying in an hour - on a Mac now and working on other stuff. Thank you.

Comment: Found a way to include a .ps1 file. Basically . .\MyFunctions.ps1 Will try soon. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks again for helping me. Leaning towards the smaller script. I tried it, it works great except for it leaves out the "records" that don't have matching "rules". I tried putting an "else" statement but that didnt get me the desired result. Basically if there are no matching descriptions in the rules csv, we should get an empty category and topic. Hope that makes sense. Thank you!!

Comment: ` $a=Import-Csv "records.csv"
 $b=Import-Csv "rules.csv"


 $rules_app = foreach ($record in $a) {
  $unmatched = $true
  foreach ($obj in $b) {
   if ($obj.Description -eq $record.Description) {
    $record | select *, @{n='Category';e={$obj.Category}}, @{n='Topic';e={$obj.Topic}}
    $unmatched = $false
   }
  }
  if ($unmatched) {
   $record | select *, @{n='Category';e="Please select"}, @{n='Topic';e="Please enter"}
  }
 } 
 $rules_app | Export-csv "rules_applied.csv" -NoTypeInformation`